# JOGL 1.x unsigned applet possible?

Tags: java, applet, jogl, unsigned

I have an applet that uses JOGL 1.x. I need to embed it in a page so that it displays without any popup security warnings, etc. (if this is possible with some form of signed applet as well then please advise how I get that set up instead).

The JOGLAppletLauncher appears depreciated for various reasons.

Using the JNLPAppletLauncher seems to fail as a result of not being able to find my applet's class. Presumably this is due to the security changes implemented a ways back. This does however work in Safari (but not chrome) on a mac which appears to not care about signed/unsigned sandbox mixing or something. This also works on windows in chrome or IE 8 IF the security is set to allow mixed sandboxing.

There are various approaches to using a JNLP file to trigger the applet, but all have failed in my attempts on all browsers on all OS's.

Is this just an impossibility these days (as implied by http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=429) and JOGL applets are just dead as a result, or is there an alternative that I have yet to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Sun was running the JOGL project they signed the jars with a special certificate which allowed it to be used as an applet without any security dialogs showing.

However Sun (Now Oracle) cancelled the JOGL project and no longer support it.

JOGL however lives on as a community supported project, JOGL2, but no longer has the benefit of the special security dialog free certificate.

So your options for using Java OpenGL applets are to either use the out dated and now pretty much broken JOGL1 which is signed by the special certificate or use a more modern OpenGL binding (like JOGL2 or LWJGL) which work much better but display a security dialog.

Comment: Thanks for this info, very helpful. However my project builds and runs beautifully under JOGL1 and the MOST important aspect is embedding without security warnings so it just runs within a page no questions. Nothing I can find seems to work but I don't know if it's not possible because of a JRE change or something else. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Gavin is right and we do not maintain JOGL 1 anymore. Please switch to JOGL 2.0 as soon as possible. We won't backport any fixes of JOGL 2.0 in JOGL 1.1.1a, only JOGL 2 is guaranteed to work with future versions of Windows for example. If you need some help, please go to the official forum of JOGL on jogamp.org.